# What is the correct way to prepare dataset for machine learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-analysis, statistics

First of all, thank you for reading this post.

I am a noob when it comes to machine learning and I am trying to use ML to classify some data. Now I have done some basic reading on supervised and unsupervised learning algorithms such as decision trees, clustering, neural networks ..etc.

What I'm struggling to understand is the correct overall procedure for preparing datasets for a ML problem.

How do I prepare the dataset for ML so that I can measure the accuracy of the algorithms?

My current understanding is that to assess accuracy, the algorithm should be fed with pre-labelled results (from a significant subset of the dataset?) so as to assess the difference between the expected outcome and the algorithm's decision?

If this is correct then how does one go about pre-labelling large datasets? My dataset is quite big and manual labelling is not feasible.

Also, any tips on doing machine learning in Python would be much appreciated!

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Best regards,

Mike

Comment: This is an extremely broad question. Labelling/annotating data is expensive: researchers pay students, pay anonymous strangers on Mechanical Turk and probably use a bunch of other methods that I'm not familiar with. A lot of research is done using standard datasets to a) enable quantitative comparison between techniques and b) not have to worry about labelling.... In Python some datasets are included in sklearn - http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#loading-an-example-dataset - or more generally look here: http://mark.reid.name/blog/a-meta-index-of-data-sets.html

Comment: Thanks Mr E. Mechanical Turk is a good shout!

Answer (score 4):

This is the most important part of any machine learning algorithm. You need to build your dataset, extract, make, scale, normalize features.

If you want to use some supervised learning algorithm, you need labeled data. There is several ways to achieve this:

1. Lebel it by hand.
2. Use some unsupervised learning algorithm to label data.

You need to use some python machine-learning toolkit, for example - scikit-learn. scikit-learn contains many useful tools for data mangling, feature extraction and preprocessing. For example, it can vectorize your data with DictVictorizer. You can add missing values, scale and normalize features using only scikit-learn.

I recommend to start with examples here - http://scikit-learn.org/stable/

Comment: I would strongly disagree with option "2". While using semi-supervised methods are getting some interesting results (like labeling part of the data, training model in supervised fashion and then training on the set labeled with the model itself) - labeling in unsupervised fashion is rather pointless approach. If one can find an unsupervised model to cluster the data, then why would we approximate this model by training another one on this data? Of course there are some scenarios and advanced methods that use such an approach,but giving it as an option to the beginer in ML field is simply wrong

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lain and lejlot. It's a shame that not enough attention has been paid towards this procedure as it has strong implications on the results. 

This leads on to the next question, say if I label data manually, what would be an acceptable size for a training dataset? Is there any "norms" or "accepted" threshold for dataset size?

Comment: You can also use some automated and manual procedures... Like using Amawon Mechanical Turk, or Fiverr...